# select lines begin with and finish with

Tags: powershell, select, line, cpu-word

I have a Powershell script with XAML code (for display some windows and buttons)
I try to replace a value of all lines begin with $computer.selectedvalue and finnish by ",1" in a text file.

My text file content :

```
COMPUTER01,SITE01,PRINTER01,1
COMPUTER05,SITE02,PRINTER01,0
COMPUTER01,SITE03,PRINTER08,1
```

end with `,1` is the printer by default and `,0` is the secondary printer

Powershell code :

```
$PLPrinterArray = Get-Printer  -ComputerName srvprint | select name
foreach ($PLPrinterArray in $PLPrinterArray) { 
  [void]$WPFCboPL.items.add(",PL,$($PLPrinterArray.Name)")
} 

$LDAPComputerArray = Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase"OU=Ordinateurs,DC=MyDC,DC=Mydomain,DC=org" -Properties name
foreach ($LDAPComputerArray in $LDAPComputerArray) { 
  [void]$WPFCboComputer.items.add($($LDAPComputerArray.Name))
}

$WPFBoutonDefaut.Add_Click({
  #If (Get-Content C:\Users\User\desktop\test.txt
  $($WPFCboComputer.selectedvalue)^ ",1$") {
  #-replace ",1",",0"}
  Add-Content -path "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt"
  -value"`n$($WPFCboComputer.selectedvalue)$($WPFCboPL.SelectedValue)$($WPFCboLN.SelectedValue),1"
})
```

Is it possible to do this and especially in a `Button.Add.Click`?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with the `-Regex` and `-File` options:

```sh
$WPFBoutonDefaut.Add_Click({

  $file = 'C:\Users\User\desktop\test.txt'

  # Process the input file line by line with regex matching,
  # and collect the potentially modified lines in an array.
  [array] $modifiedlines = 
    switch -Regex -File $file {
      "^($($WPFCboComputer.SelectedValue),.+,)1$" { $Matches[1] + '0' }
      default { $_ } # pass through
    }

  # Save the modified lines plus the new line back to the file.
  # Note: Use -Encoding as needed.
  Set-Content $file -Value (
    $modifiedLines + "$($WPFCboComputer.SelectedValue)$($WPFCboPL.SelectedValue)$($WPFCboLN.SelectedValue),1"
  )

})
```